# Problems sorting with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: xcode, sorting, nssortdescriptor, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using an NSFetchedResultsController to retrieve data for a UITableView. It works fine. Now I need to place three buttons which should trigger different sorting on the table view. To achieve this I implemented:

```
switch (selectedOrder) {
    case 0:
        sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
        break;
    case 1: 
        /*
        sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"price"  ascending: NO 
                                                    comparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
                                                        NSLog(@"Test");
                                                        return numSort(obj1, obj2, nil);
                                                        //return NSOrderedSame;
                                                    }];
         */
        sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"price" 
                                                     ascending: NO 
                                                      selector:@selector(compareAsFloats:)];

        break;
    ...
    default:
        break;}
```

I don't seem to find a way to get the second case (price) working. In fact, if I use the block, it does take into account the property, but as a string, not as a number. It is like the code in the block wasn't executed at all. In fact if I just return NSOrderedSame it still orders it as a string. And the log is not performed. If I use the @selector(compareAsFloats:) version, where the method is defined on a NSString category, I get a runtime error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unsupported NSSortDescriptor selector: compareAsFloats:'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x014df5a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01889313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreData                            0x01211266 -[NSSQLGenerator newSQLStatementForFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:countOnly:nestingLevel:] + 1270
    3   CoreData                            0x011494d8 -[NSSQLAdapter _newSelectStatementWithFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:] + 488
    4   CoreData                            0x011492e1 -[NSSQLAdapter newSelectStatementWithFetchRequest:] + 49
    5   CoreData                            0x0114918e -[NSSQLCore newRowsForFetchPlan:] + 430
    .....   .....
)
```

I must be making a very trivial mistake.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

you can't do that. If you use a SQLite backend for Core Data the ordering works on SQL level.
You can't use custom comparison selectors or blocks. You have to solely sort by attributes of your entity

Why don't you save price as a decimal number (that's a [NSDecimalNumber](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) which does not have the accuracy problems like double and float.

You could then just use price to sort your data.

Answer (score -1):

The way I accomplished this was by defining the sort in the IBAction of a button and creating the NSFetchRequest *request in @property. In the button action i am doing this:

```
self.request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"distance" ascending:YES]];
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
[tableView reloadData];
```